# Overpass API default output format

Tags: r, overpass-api

I installed local Overpass API from Docker container (https://github.com/wiktorn/Overpass-API). Everything works, server is accepting queries and is giving valid answers.

What's the problem?

I'm struggling with R language *osmdata* package to draw maps. Making long story short, my local Overpass server gives responses in JSON format (*Content-Type: application/json*) but (probably) package expects them in OSM XML (*Content-Type: application/osm3s+xml*).

I see in my logs during making test query:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2023:10:23:18 +0000] "POST /api/interpreter HTTP/1.1" 200 308 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2023:10:23:26 +0000] "GET /api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node(1);out; HTTP/1.1" 200 658 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

"Asking" (from terminal) curl version is 7.81.0, "responding" curl (from Overpass API Docker container) is 7.74.0.

How can I force Overpass API server to give replies in osm3s+xml format?

Which config files should I check?

Comment: You need to fix your Overpass query! Since you're requesting JSON output format by adding [out:json] to your query, the response will use JSON format. You'd better either say [out:xml] or don't provide any [out ... ] setting at all.

Comment: In the meantime I used to know what I need. But thank you :)